# fetch wrongly double inserts into database

Tags: javascript, php, fetch-api, svelte

I'm using fetch to send data to a PHP script. Only Problem is that it inserts empty data first and then the correct one.
I'm sending a JSON string which then gets decode with PHP.

I've tested the script with Postman and it works fine there.

Java-Script Code:

```
async function uploadImage() {
      let url = "http://localhost/upload_image.php";
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(writePosition);
      let dataJSON = {"Koordinate_X":3, "Koordinate_Y":1, "Kategorie":1, "Bild":"Es klappt aus der App"};

      fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
        /*headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }, REMOVED*/
        body: JSON.stringify(dataJSON)
      })
    };
```

HTML Code:

```
<button on:click={uploadImage}>Upload</button>
```

PhP Code:

```
<?php 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:  http://localhost:5173');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers:  Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Authorization, Origin');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods:  POST, PUT');

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
print_r($data);

//path to database file
$database_path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "\WoIstMein.accdb";
//check file exist before we proceed
if (!file_exists($database_path)) {
    die("Access database file not found !");
}

//create a new PDO object
$database = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=$database_path;");

try{    
$sql = 'INSERT INTO Gegenstaende (Koordinate_X, Koordinate_Y, Kategorie, Bild) VALUES (:koord_x,:koord_y,:kategorie,:bild);';
$statement = $database->prepare($sql);
$result = $statement->execute(array('koord_x' => $data["Koordinate_X"],'koord_y' => $data["Koordinate_Y"],'kategorie' => $data["Kategorie"], 'bild' => $data["Bild"]));
$database = null;
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Comment: Server code is probably irrelevant. Is that the entire HTML or is there a `form` around the button? Have you checked network info in the browser dev tools? It should show all requests, so if multiple are sent from the front end, they should end up there. There can also be an "initiator" column which shows where the request comes from (e.g. a script).

Comment: what does `writePosition` do and can you add to the question?

Comment: perhaps the OPTIONS is sent, for cors, just return a `200 ok` on the request for the OPTIONS http verb, this should fix your issue

Comment: Please do *not* add answers to the question. Just post an answer yourself and accept that once you are allowed to. That way the question will no longer be shown as unanswered.

Comment: Thanks you for giving feedback after solving your problem, but I think the right solution should be for your server code to check the method (GET, OPTIONS...) of the request it's getting, and act accordingly -- that is, not do DB operations on OPTIONS and all, notably. Just saying... Also, I believe it's better for StackOverflow's tracking purposes if you post your own answer with your solution and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to H.B. I got the answer. I checked the network info and saw my app was sending two requests. Because of the headers tag I submitted in the fetch() command. So fetch first did an preflight to check the options and then commited the actual post command. So my solution was that I removed the "headers" from fetch.